# FTP file send incorrectly

Tags: ftp

we have afew label printer A4+ and we use them to print a huge amount of label for our warehouse, beacause we want to print lables which each of them is diffrent from another we decide to make a DBF file for each print job, so each time the DBF file contain number of diffrent  record then our web service make a ftp request to A4+ printer and ftp the DBF file to the printer , then the print command send to printer and the DBF file will print. most of the time all of the steps take happen successfully but sometimes the DBF file on the printer is little diffrent from the dbf file was made on the web service and the diffrence is on the header of file , this diiffrence cause to the problem so the printer prints the labels but not to the end of DBF file, for example if the DBF file contain 500 records, printer print just 300 record or diffrent number and then it continue to print but the label contain no data, it means after 300 printer dont read the dbf file and the label is quite raw, but beacause the print command is  500 (DBF file also contain 500 records) it continue to feed the label until 500.

we compare both of DBF file on the server which hosts the web service(this is where we create dbf file) and the file that ftp on the printer, they are the same, just a bit on the header of file is diiffrent and it makes this problem.

i include the code we make DBF file and also the code we use to ftp this file to printer and also i attach both DBF file for a sample.

our team works on the project and we study the helps on your web site, but at this point as we can see everything is ok and we could nt debug this case, maybe you can help us to solve this.

------------------------Create DBF file ------------------------------------------------------

```
   private bool EportDBF(string filePath, List<BarcodeData> list)
   {
       string tableName = string.Empty;
       string folderPath = string.Empty;

       GetFileNameAndPath(filePath, ref tableName, ref folderPath);

       string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + folderPath + "; Extended Properties=DBASE IV;";
       string createStatement = "Create Table " + tableName + " ( ";
       string insertStatement = "Insert Into " + tableName + " Values ( ";
       string insertTemp = string.Empty;

       OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

       try
       {

           createStatement += "[RW] varchar(4), ";
           createStatement += "[CODE] varchar(16), ";
           createStatement += "[DESC] varchar(16), ";
           createStatement += "[WEIGHT] varchar(16), ";
           createStatement += "[DATE] varchar(32), ";
           createStatement += "[RCODE] varchar(16), ";
           createStatement += "[BCODE] varchar(16) )";

           conn.Open();

           DataSet dsFill = new DataSet();

           OleDbDataAdapter daInsertTable = new OleDbDataAdapter(createStatement, conn);

           daInsertTable.Fill(dsFill);

           int row = 1001;

           foreach (var item in list)
           {
               insertTemp = insertStatement;

               insertTemp += "'" + row++ + "' , ";
               insertTemp += "'" + item.ItemCode + "' , ";
               insertTemp += "'0' , ";
               insertTemp += "'" + item.Weight + "' , ";
               insertTemp += "'" + item.DateTime + "' , ";
               insertTemp += "'" + item.ReferenceCode + "' , ";
               insertTemp += "'" + item.Barcode.ToString() + "' ) ;";

               daInsertTable = new OleDbDataAdapter(insertTemp, conn);

               daInsertTable.Fill(dsFill);
           }

           conn.Close();
           conn.Dispose();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           conn.Close();
           conn.Dispose();

           return false;
       }

       return true;
   }
```

------------------------FTP DBF file to printer-------------------------------------------

```
   private bool UpLoadDBF(List<BarcodeData> barcodeDatas, string path)
   {
       try
       {
           EportDBF(path, barcodeDatas);

           FtpWebRequest request;
           FtpWebResponse response;

           Stream sourceStream = new MemoryStream();
           Stream requestStream = sourceStream;
           StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

           try
           {
               request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + printerIP + "/card/barcodes.dbf");
               request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
               request.KeepAlive = false;
               request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);

               byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
               sourceStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

               try
               {
                   requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
               }
               finally 
               {
                   request.ContentLength = sourceStream.Length;

                   byte[] buffer = new byte[sourceStream.Length];
                   int count = 2048;
                   if (sourceStream.Length < count)
                       count = (int) sourceStream.Length;

                   int bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, count);

                   do
                   {
                       requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                       bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, count);

                   } while (bytesRead > 0);

                   sourceStream.Close();
                   requestStream.Close();
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
           }
           finally
           {
               request = null;

               sourceStream.Close();
               sourceStream.Dispose();

               reader.Close();
               reader.Dispose();

               requestStream.Close();
               requestStream.Dispose();
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return false;
       }

       return true;
   }
```

---

So thanks inadvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don know why you have used Encoding.Default.GetBytes to read the bytes.Instead of that use the FileStream's Read method to read the bytes. Hope this helps.